# SQL - Select only one value from multiple fields

Tags: sql

Assume the following

```
col1      col2       col3       col4
------+----------+---------+---------
abc   |          |         |
```

Yes, col1-4 have a space in them!

I want to select the column that is not a space .  On row 1 it's col1, but on row 20 it may be col3, row 55 it may be col2, and so on.  I need to return just that column.

There will always be only one column with a stored value within this range of four columns, **I just need the one that actually has information in it**.

This will be part of a greater query for a report, so regardless of what column `abc` is in I need that to look the same in every result case.  Meaning I can't have the results be `col1` for one case and `col2` for the other because the report won't recognize.  The column needs to always be called the same.

Yes, I know it's better to store NULLS versus spaces and why use four columns when only one can have data, why not use one. I've complained enougth about that so don't rip me a new one about bad db design because I AGREE.

Comment: About "ripping you a new one"- why learn it badly if you want to the final product to be better?

Comment: Why not use a `CASE` statement, like `CASE WHEN col1 <> ' ' THEN col1 WHEN col2 <> ' ' THEN col2...`

Comment: @BlueIce fixing an existing report.  Later we will upgrade and fix all of this nonsense.

Comment: @gSaenz Well, at least you'll fix it in the future. Good enough for me :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(col1 + col2 + col3 + col4))
```

Here we go... Why not add bad code to bad design. You could technically add all of the columns together and then trim them for leading/trailing spaces. I don't recommend it for performance on large scale deployments. Heck, I don't recommend this for any production script but I've been here before... Gotta do what you can to get it done.

Comment: Of course! The second I posted I thought this also.  And I agree with your statement, this is not recommended!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a CASE statement, like

```
CASE WHEN col1 <> ' ' THEN col1
    WHEN col2 <> ' ' THEN col2
    WHEN col3 <> ' ' THEN col3
    WHEN col4 <> ' ' THEN col4
END
```

Comment: this returns four columns, only need one.

Comment: @gSaenz This returns only one value per row.

Comment: yes, my apologies I didn't read thoroughly.  It works but the trim suggestion works better as a whole with the other code.  Thank you!

Comment: @gSaenz NP, I think the `TRIM` solution is a nifty one too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
case 
   when col1 != '' then col1
   when col2 != '' then col2
   ...
end
```